# cannot create object in IE using new Keyword

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var com = {};
var com.Project = function(){
   this.display = function(){
   alert("hai.....");
   }
}
var project_obj = new com.Project();
```

while creating the project_obj i got an error in IE9 like "Object doesn't support this action"

this code working well in firefox and chrome.
i have given a sample code.
i'm trying to use Classes and package concept in javastript.

i don't know why this error came in IE.

Comment: Can you give me your project link?

Comment: my project in intranet ...
i can't share my project outside...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qv6BW/ code avilable in jsfiddle please review my code

Comment: http://jsbin.com/otoyim/10/edit in this link project has working very fine

Answer (score 2):

This is illegal in all browsers and raises a syntax error :

```
var com.Project = function(){
```

You may do this :

```
var com = {}; // whatever
com.Project = function(){
```

Comment: still i got a problem in creating new object

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem you have in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? We don't have enough information to know what it is.

Comment: `Class : {` ? What are you attempting ? This isn't a propert JS construct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the 1st line, as variable names cannot include `.`.

If you're trying to [namespace](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/), you need to first define `com` as an `Object` with `Project` as one of its properties:

```
var com = {
    Project: function () {
        // etc.
    }
};
```

Comment: still i got a problem in creating new object

Answer (score 0):

Based on the working link to your javascript code I think you should change this

```
$.extend(true, window, container[0]);
```

to

```
$.extend(true, window, d);
```